# Pub folder index file not working

Tags: folder

Here is my website url of pub folder https://www.marketplace.jawadditaksal.org/pub/

when I installed Magento in the server by default Magento adds two `.htaccess` files: one in the domain directory and one in `/pub`, which I have renamed to **".htaccess_no"** because at that time website css was not working so in the pub folder I renamed the `htacess` file from `"htacess"` to `"htacess_no"` and website was working and which is now working also.

But the problem is when user open the url https://www.marketplace.jawadditaksal.org/pub/ its shows the website in a wrong way, what is the solution of the pub folder index file, how normally Magento websites handle pub folder. should I add empty index file in the pub folder?

Comment: Don't rename htaccess of pub folder. Are you running your website from pub folder?

Comment: why are you trying /pub when https://www.marketplace.jawadditaksal.org/ is just working fine

Comment: @SukumarGorai no I am not running my website from pub folder, problem was when I installed the magento 2.3 with the demo, at that time main domain directory website css was not working so my server company found the solution that to rename the htacess file of the pub folder, at that time website was working which is also working now, but problem is when someone manually open the website pub folder websitename/pub then on that case it shows the pub folder index file which looks bad.

Comment: @PhilippSander Website is working fine because I edit the name of the .htacess file which is in the pub folder previous name was `.htacess` at present its name is `htacess_no` but problem is when someone manually open the website pub folder websitename/pub then on that case it shows the pub folder index file which looks bad

Comment: you should not do ANYTHING with the .htaccess in pub. why did you change it?

Comment: @PhilippSander I did not change the content of .htacess in the pub folder, I just change the name of the htacess in the pub folder from `htacess` to `htacess_no` because if i did not change the name of the `htacess` in the pub folder then the main website is not working

Comment: you need the file exactly with that name. if the page is not working you have something on your webserver configured wrong

Comment: please provide your apaches vhost config in the question

Comment: @PhilippSander Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built: Sep 18 2017 16:37:54

Comment: that not the vhost config

Comment: @PhilippSander could you please explain where can i found this.

Comment: in your site-available directory of your apache2

Comment: @PhilippSander see now what I did is Create a new HTML file and new .htacess file in the pub folder and older one I changed the name to index.old and htacess.old, so now when someone type this url https://www.marketplace.jawadditaksal.org/pub/ it will redirect to main index website. it is fine now?

Comment: I still don't  get why you changed something in the pub/ folder in the firstplace...

Comment: @PhilippSander As I mention earlier that when I check the website url `/pub` its seems like some thing opens but css not working, so that is why I redirect that to main website.

Comment: @PhilippSander same problem I found in this website http://themes.magesolution.com/claue/m2/pub/  http://themes.magesolution.com/claue/m2/